In The Lord of the Rings, did anyone ever say "The fellowship is now complete."?
I have seen some references to this quote, but can't confirm if it was a real line, in either the books or movies. Is it perhaps a Mandela effect, or a reference from something else?

It does sound a bit like 'The circle is now complete' said by Darth Vader in A New Hope :)

For the book, check out https://search.digitaltolkien.com/?terms=fellowship+ (and to figure out in your own copy what the paragraph references point to, see https://digitaltolkien.com/data/lotr-citation-system.txt) Though Jiminy points out "complete appears once, I disagree: https://search.digitaltolkien.com/?terms=complete+

The entirety of the Fellowship membership was decided upon during a single meeting, and the title of 'Fellowship' only came up at the end of it.   I can't think of a point that 'the fellowship is now complete" would fit the narrative.

@DavidRoberts I don't know where I have put my books. It's my recollection that Elrond sighs and says something like, "Very well, the Fellowship is complete" or "That completes the Fellowship" after Gandalf tells him that Merry and Pippin must be included for arbitrary reasons. Or, perhaps Elrond says that two more are needed to "complete" the Fellowship to make the number of members nine. Tolkien may not have known it, but the Nine against Nine suggests baseball. It has inspired jokes.

@Wastrel see the answer by Nullius.

@DavidRoberts Thanks. That answer wasn't there when I commented, or I would not have. That's an actual quote from the book, and it's "the tale of Nine is 'filled'" not complete. I need to find my books.

@Wastrel no problem! I just wanted to ping you as you may not have seen the answer.

Not that phrase, no.
The movie (extended version):

MERRY:    Wait! we're
coming too!   They run and join the others.  [Elrond looks astounded]
MERRY:    You'd have to send us home tied up in a sack to stop us
PIPPIN:   Anyway you need people of intelligence on this sort of mission
...........quest ..........thing
MERRY:    Well that rules you out Pip
ELROND:   (looks at the nine stood together) Nine companions... So be
it! You shall be the Fellowship of the Ring!
PIPPIN:   Great! Where are we going?

Indeed, in the Harper Collins 50th anniversary edition, the word "complete" appears a few times but never in a sentence referring to the fellowship.
I didn't search the sequels as the fellowship is broken by the end of the first of the three books/films.

https://search.digitaltolkien.com/?terms=complete+ finds 13 occurrences.

Correct, if you zoom into the detail, you find that many of those are in the foreword and all in the text are the adverbial forms (completely) or one of "incomplete". @DavidRoberts There's just a single instance of "complete". If you find a single other I'll eat my pointy hat.

To be completely precise, there are two instances of complete as an adjective: "A  shudder  ran through  the  tree  from  root  to  tip,  and  complete  silence  fell. " and "well  over  twenty  miles  from  end to  end.  But,  of  course,  it  was  not  a  complete  protection."

@Greenonline Damn, must have skimmed those without counting them. Oh, well, there goes another hat.

@JiminyCricket. "complete" appears in Book 1 ch 3,5,6, Book 2 ch 2, Book 3 ch 3, Book 4 ch 1,8, Book 5 ch 9, Book 6 ch 1,4 (none in the foreword). But "incomplete" only appears in Book 2 ch 3. :-) I'm fairly sure James Tauber knows what he's doing with search tools. I'm really curious why your search didn't find them.

Hang on @DavidRoberts, I only have the one hat to eat here! Perhaps I should edit.

"Complete" is found as a partial string of incomplete and completely. I searched the text using Windows built-in find tool. I did find the instances, but skipped all but the part noted in my answer. @DavidRoberts

@DavidRoberts -  I thought that we were only searching "Fellowship of the ring" ( i.e Books 1 and 2) as after that, the fellowship no longer exists, so there is no point in looking any further..? (As indeed noted in the answer)

@Greenonline As Fellowship contains Book 1 and Book 2, "complete"  appears in four different chapters. I didn't think to stop looking, nor to limit myself to the event that the OP was referring to. I thought Jiminy was claiming a search result across the whole of LotR, which you can see might have seemed odd!

@JiminyCricket was just looking for an excuse to do some version of the pointy hat trick.

In the book, the words are a little different.

'Let it be so, then. You shall go,' said Elrond, and he sighed. 'Now the tale of Nine is filled. In seven days the Company must depart.'


Is it on the same page that he says “Against nine riders we shall set nine walkers”?

@AntonSherwood - one page before (359 vs 360), and the quote is reversed: ‘... and  the  Nine
Walkers  shall  be  set  against  the  Nine  Riders...

I suspected it was "tale of", but don't have an copy to the text to hand.

This quote seems the closest in spirit. +1

Just prior to the quote in Nullius's answer (one page before, i.e. page 359 vs page 360, to be precise) is yet another similar sounding line that states the requirement for the fellowship to be complete (emphasis is mine):

‘The  Company  of  the  Ring  shall  be  Nine;  and  the  Nine
Walkers  shall  be  set  against  the  Nine  Riders  that  are  evil.
With  you  and  your  faithful  servant,  Gandalf  will  go;  for  this
shall  be  his  great  task,  and  maybe  the  end  of  his  labours.*

In other words, it is the quote in the answer from Nullius which implies that it is complete. The quote above merely states what it needs to be in order to be complete.

If I remember correctly (it has been a few years since I read the books) there is also paragraph around there were Elrond states that if Merry and Pippin hadn't invited themselves to the Nine he would have selected some Elves from his household to arrive at 9 members.

@Tonny - ‘There  remain  two  more  to  be  found,’  said  Elrond.  ‘These
I  will  consider.  Of  my  household  I  may  find  some  that  it
seems  good  to  me  to  send.’ - 6 paragraphs later, still on page 359 (check the link).

I wasn't that far off then. Amazing what details you can sometimes remember. Must have been late 90's when I last read the books.

@Tonny - I read it just after that weird cartoon version (that ends at Helm's Deep) came out - whenever that was. I had the edition that had a photo (of the dark riders leaving Hobbiton?) from the film on the cover.

You mean the Ralph Bakshi movie from 1978? I've still got a copy of that lying around somewhere on the harddisk. It was originally supposed to be 2 movies, but part 2 was never released. As far as I recall it was 99% done, but never released due to some legal dispute between the United Artists film-studio having the publication rights and the Bakshi production studio doing the actual work.
